# Using trig to determine angles from a compound cut

Tags: cutting

Trigonometry was never my strong point so any help would be much appreciated.

Below is an image of a solid square section bar with a compound cut at one end. Given the two angles α & β (which are measured from a plane perpendicular to the bar's neutral axis to an edge on the cut face), is there any way one can determine the angles γ & θ? Where γ is the single cut angle from the imaginary plane to the face and θ is the amount the bar has to rotate so that the cut face is perpendicular to the sheet or worktop.

Thanks
[image]

Edit: Labelled image added to correspond with r13's reply:
[image]

Edit 2:
Here is a table of different α & β angles with γ & θ measured:

| α | β | γ | θ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35 | 65 | 66.1 | 18.1 |
| 15 | 12 | 18.9 | 51.6 |
| 45 | 45 | 54.7 | 45.0 |
| 10 | 47 | 47.4 | 9.3 |
| 50 | 37 | 54.7 | 57.7 |

Comment: I tried a few different ways, but I don't get `17.5 deg` as the answer. Are you sure that `66 deg` and `17.5 deg` are correct results ?

Comment: Yes, as this is a cad drawing. I know one should start with something like cosθ = tanα/tanβ, but this is incorrect by itself.

Comment: Is the `17.5 deg` in cad arrived at by rotating the object by *trial-and-error* and visually checking the projection ? Or did you use some function in CAD to **compute** this number ? What function in the cad did you use to find the required rotation ? I can think of some methods to arrive at the answer; but it is not `17.5 deg`.

Comment: Yes, rotated by eye to align the two edges to give me the perpendicular face. How close are you getting? I have just double checked and it is more like θ = 18.075° and γ = 66.09°. Right now, to the nearest 0.5° is acceptable. 
If you can share your method I can test with other cut angles.

Comment: I am getting `18.02 deg`. The formula is $\tan\theta = \tan\alpha / \tan\beta$. I will attempt an answer later when I get time.

Comment: Yes! That works. Thank you! Any idea how I would calculate γ? If it helps I have added a table of different angles using your formula with γ measured to the original question. (formatting makes it difficult to put here)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This may not be the shortest or most intuitive way of calculating the required angles.

Starting from the diagram drawn in the other answer and using similar naming convention, and adding some axis names also (X,Y,Z) for convenience,

[image: picture of cut beam]

What are needed:

1. The angle $\gamma$ between the plane *abcd* and the XZ plane.
2. Rotation angle $\theta$ about the Y axis required to bring the plane *abcd* parallel to X axis (or Z axis depending on which view are looking through).

Instead of working with planes, it may be easier to work with **normals** to the planes. Translating the above two requirements, we have:

1. Angle between $\vec{n}$, the normal to *abcd*, and $\vec{y}$, the normal to XZ plane.
2. Rotation about Y axis required to bring $\vec{n}$ to ZY plane (or XY plane depending on which view we are looking through); i.e., Angle between projection of $\vec{n}$ on XZ plane and and $\vec{z}$ (or $\vec{x}$).

To start, we need expression for $\vec{n}$.

$$\begin{align}
\vec{n} ={}& \vec{da}\times \vec{dc}\\
\vec{da} ={}& 0\ \vec{x} - \tan{35}\ \vec{y} + 1\ \vec{z}\\
\vec{dc} ={}& 1\ \vec{x} - \tan{65}\ \vec{y} + 0\ \vec{z}\\
\implies \vec{n} ={}& \tan{65}\ \vec{x} + 1\ \vec{y} + \tan{35}\ \vec{z}\\
\mathrm{proj}_{XZ}(\vec{n}) ={}& \tan{65}\ \vec{x} + \color{red}{0}\ \vec{y} + \tan{35}\ \vec{z}
\end{align}
$$

So, after translating the original problem, to that of finding angles between vectors, we can use the dot product or cross product formulae to find the angles.

1. Angle between $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{y}$ is $cos^{-1}(\frac{\vec{n}\cdot\vec{y}}{|\vec{n}| |\vec{y}|}) = 66.09339\deg$
2. Angle between $\mathrm{proj}_{XZ}\vec{n}$ and $\vec{z}$ is $cos^{-1}(\frac{\mathrm{proj}_{XZ}\vec{n}\cdot\vec{z}}{|\mathrm{proj}_{XZ}\vec{n}| |\vec{z}|}) = 71.9175111\deg = (90-18.0824888)\deg$

### Alternate method for $\theta$

Directly using trigonometry. Again, we start from the figure. We mark $\theta$ in the figure.

$$
\begin{align}
\tan\theta ={}& \frac{ef}{af}\\
{}={}& \frac{ef}{1}\\
{}={}& \frac{gd}{1} & (ef = gd)\\
{}={}& \frac{eg / \tan{65}}{1} & (eg/gd = \tan{65})\\
{}={}& \frac{fd}{\tan{65}} & (eg = fd)\\
{\tan{\theta}}={}& \frac{\tan{35}}{\tan{65}}
\end{align}
$$

[image: using trigonometry]

Comment: wow, thank you so much. That does help get my head round it. I have also discovered that **tan γ = tan β / cos θ** I will update if I find a solution using α

Comment: update: of course **tan γ = tan α / (90 - cos θ)**. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is for the top block. If it helps, you can do the same for the bottom block. (First to determine the view, then label corner to corner)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the original post to contain the rotated view with the corners and views labelled. Do you have an idea of how to solve the problem?